# What is bootstrap in jsquery and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Of late, I have started learning css and html. I came across bootstraps.

What are bootstraps in css and js?
Why do we need to use it?
What if we dont use it?

Also any links to study the bootstraps in detail

Thanks

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/